# Disable notifications while watching videos or listening to music

Tags: settings, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, youtube

Is it possible to disable WhatsApp Status bar notifications while watching YouTube videos on a Android device or while playing music on Android device?

I don't want to disable WhatsApp notifications in any other conditions, but only when I am watching videos or while listening to music/song.

I know it is possible to disable notifications of an app (like WhatsApp), but that will block it for all the time. This I don't want to happen. I would like to continue to receive WhatsApp notifications but not while watching videos or while listening to music/song.

My Device: Micromax Canvas 4
 
Android OS: 4.2

Is this possible?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/147995/do-not-mute-sound-on-incoming-notification-android-youtube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are watching youtube, temporary put your phone on silent.

However you can also use this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pierceholdings.dontpause&hl=en

Comment: Of course I can do that, but don't think that is smart way of using Smart phone :)

Comment: Try this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pierceholdings.dontpause&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the link! Looks promising while Music Listening, Will give it a try with YouTube!

Comment: the app link that you gave worked perfectly. It puts device always in VIBRATE mode while music is getting played! And this is enough for me as it dont make notification sound!

Answer (score 0):

Or activate the *blocking mode* from the notification panel then disable it when you finish. It's just a five second easy process!

Answer (score 0):

With new Android 8, you can use Game mode to stop that.
It will activate and turn off automatically depending on what app you want.

Comment: I just want to know which Android device  you are using. AFAIK, only selected devices such as OnePlus' devices comes with it. BTW, OP asked for Android 4.2.