# Do not mute Sound on incoming notification - Android, YouTube

Tags: notifications, audio, mute

**Is there an option to manage sound notification behaviour on a Android phone?**

*Description:*
In the morning, I do watch YouTube lectures, but every minute or so I do receive Slack message, that mute the voice in the video for 5 seconds. It is really annoying, and hard to listen the lecture.

**How it should be:**

```
Option 1: Allow a notification to interrupt the sound/video stream without muting it (so the 'bip' would overlay/merge to the sound stream, but the video would continue).
Option 2: (the current system state): Mute the application, but do not stop the video (very annoying)!
Option 3: Mute the application, but stop the stream/video/music.
```

I know that there are some option to mute the phone (manual), or install an app (automatic), but I do not wan't do mute the notification itself. I do want to hear it, just without muting the sound/video/music that is currently playing!

My system Android 5, Samsung Galaxy S5

Greetings
Jakub

Related topic:
[Disable Notification while watching Videos or Listening Music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103106/disable-notification-while-watching-videos-or-listening-music)

Answer (score 0):

The [Don't Pause!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pierceholdings.dontpause) app promises to help here:

> Are you tired of Notifications interrupting your music?
>   […]
>   Don't Pause was designed to keep your device from interrupting you when you are listening to music. If you are listening to music through your android phone and you get a text message or email, by default, Android pauses your music and plays the notification. Don't Pause fills in here. Don't Pause will run continuously once you start it and when you are playing music it automatically puts your notifications on vibrate. After you finish your music, Don't Pause automatically changes your setting back to the normal ringer.

I have not tried the app myself (no use-case for me), but a 4-star rating with more than 2.5k votes sounds promising.

Comment: I did just install don't pause, but i bet it would mute the notification sound. I'd prefer to hear them 'on the top of audio stream' :/

Comment: Not sure which one does that, but be welcome to check my list of apps for [Notification Settings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications#group_543). I could imagine *XNotifications* being capable of that, but it would require a rooted device with the XPosed framework. As for *Don't Pause:* you won't *hear* the notification but *feel* it (sweet vibrations :)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy
Unfortunately my phone is mounted in the 'holder' in most situations, so I won't feel it :(

Comment: In a "holder"? Does that implicate any connection via USB (or Bluetooth) to some other device? There might be a way re-routing the notification sound channel to a different output than the media sound, which *might* have the desired effect. I know there's an app dealing with this at least for Bluetooth, but I would have to check – it that's relevant to you. Most likely an app for [Volume control](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_871) or [Headset Volume Control](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_headset#group_331).